# Cohn measure theory -page 17

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I can't understand the proof of equation $(2)$ of the theorem $1.3.6$ (page $17$), "As to the induction step, note that the $\mu$-measurability of $B_{n+1}$ and the disjointness of the sequence $B_i$  imply that ..."  how to understand the implying equation followed.

Comment: You should quote the equation and the theorem, not everyone has the book to know what you are referencing.

Answer (score 2):

The part of Cohn's proof of Theorem 1.3.6 (b) in question:

> \begin{align}
> \mu^*(A \cap (\cap_{i=1}^n B_i^c)) &=
> \mu^*(A \cap(\cap_{i=1}^n B_i^c) \cap B_{n+1}) +  \mu^*(A \cap (\cap_{i=1}^n B_i^c) \cap B_{n+1}^c) \\
> &= \mu^*(A \cap B_{n+1}) + \mu^*(A \cap (\cap_{i=1}^{n+1} B_i^c)).
> \end{align}

The first equality follows from writing $$A \cap (\cap_{i=1}^n B_i^c) = (A \cap(\cap_{i=1}^n B_i^c) \cap B_{n+1}) \cup (A \cap(\cap_{i=1}^n B_i^c) \cap B_{n+1}^c)$$
and then using the measurability of $B_{n+1}$.

The second equality is just a simplification of the preceding line. By assumption, the $B_i$ are disjoint and so $B_{n+1} \subset \cap_{i=1}^n B_i^c$.

Comment: thanks J. Im. now I can go through this proof.